# How can one show that lim x to 0 of integral from 1 to 2 of $\frac{e^{xt}}{t}$ dt

Tags: integration, limits, proof-verification, definite-integrals

How can one show that $$\lim_{x\to 0}\int_1^2\frac{e^{xt}}{t}dt=\ln(2)$$

In class I wrote an answer to my teacher , he told me it's not true so I need a verification and an explanation of it.

Limit x to 0 of Integral from 1 to 2 $\frac{e^{xt}}{t} dt$ = integral from 1 to 2 of $\frac{e^{0t}}{t}dt$ = ln(2)-ln(1)

Comment: If it's not true, you are going to have a hard time finding verification for it. (But I suspect he meant your argument was not correct, not that the result is not true.)

Comment: heads up, integral domains are an algebraic structure and have nothing to do with integrals

Comment: @ThomasAndrews just out of curiosity, how did you verify that so fast?

Comment: You can make a change of variables, $u = e^{xt}$, which gives

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \int_{e^{x}}^{e^{2x}} \frac{du}{\ln(u)}$$

which can then be handled by integration by parts. Evaluating the integral then taking limits gives the result. Note that when integrating by parts, you get an infinite sum as one of your terms hence needs to be handled carefully.

Comment: @Mattos you're absolutely right, I noticed and deleted my comment. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @qbert Sorry, I didn't see you had deleted. All good mate.

Answer (score 1):

Your argument relies on the commutativity of limits and integrals. This is not always the case, but you can use the [Dominated convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) to show that it applies in this specific case.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible solution.

From the Maclaurin series for the exponential function the integrand may be written as
$$\frac{e^{xt}}{t} = \sum_{n \geqslant 0} \frac{(xt)^n}{n! t} = \frac{1}{t} + \sum_{n \geqslant 1} \frac{x^n t^{n - 1}}{n!},$$
which converges for all $t$. Thus
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \int_1^2 \frac{e^{xt}}{t} \, dt = \lim_{x \to 0} \int_1^2 \left [\frac{1}{t} + \sum_{n \geqslant 1} \frac{x^n t^{n - 1}}{n!} \right ] \, dt.$$
Now the order of the integral and the infinite sum can be interchanged using [Fubini's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini's_theorem) (allowing us to integrate term by term). Thus
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \to 0} \int_1^2 \frac{e^{xt}}{t} \, dt &= \lim_{x \to 0} \left [\ln t + \sum_{n \geqslant 1} \int^2_1 \frac{x^n t^{n - 1}}{n!} \, dt \right ]\\
&=\lim_{x \to 0} \left [\ln t + \sum_{n \geqslant 1} \frac{x^n t^n}{n \cdot n!} \right ]^2_1\\
&=\lim_{x \to 0} \left [\ln 2 + \sum_{n \geqslant 1} \frac{(2x)^n}{n \cdot n!} - \sum_{n \geqslant 1} \frac{x^n}{n \cdot n!} \right ]\\
&= \ln 2,
\end{align*}
as required.

Comment: What is the justification for the final step of interchanging limit and sum?

Comment: @qbert - Ah yes. Did not mention the justification for interchanging the limit and the sum comes from the dominated convergence theorem.